# Converting to unix timestamp and back again cause loss of 1 day in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I experienced a problem importing dates into MySQL. I boiled it down to this ...

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(str_to_date('201201', '%Y%m')))
```

It reports...

```
2011-12-31 00:00:00
```

To make it return the original date, is there something I need to set up with MYSQL, or do I just fiddle it and add on one day or something?

I'm in the GMT time zone.

A search returned some very old bugs about this and other posts says it was how it is supposed to happen, but I didnt understand what you are supposed to do about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On 5.5.21 (OS X) i get `2012-01-01 00:00:00`.
Try upgrading your server.

Answer (score 0):

When I run it, `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('201201', '%Y%m')` returns the invalid date `2012-01-00` (January 0th?!), so I'm not altogether surprised that round-tripping that through `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` and `FROM_UNIXTIME()` ends up messing it up. Try adding a day to make it a real date (`2012-01-01`) first.